# Passing hex as a parameter fails

Tags: php

I am trying to call a codeigniter method from vanilla php like this.

`get.php`

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'vars' => array(
        'one'   => 'hello',
        'two'   => 'world'
    )
);
function strToHex($string){
    $hex = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
    }
    return strToUpper($hex);
}


$p1 = $options["vars"]["one"];
$p2 = $options["vars"]["two"];

$en = serialize($options);
$tohex = strToHex($en);

try{
echo file_get_contents("http://localhost/app/welcome/entry/".$tohex);
$json = file_get_contents("http://localhost/app/welcome/entry/".$tohex,true);
if ($json === false) {
    echo 'Request with id'.' '.rand(5667789,790637738).' '.'was not successful.This incident was logged.';
}
}
catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

This is my codeigniter method

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
    }
    public function entry($in){
    $in = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $arr = hexToStr($in);
    $array = unserialize($arr);
    print_r($array);
    /**
    $p1 = $arr["vars"]["one"];
    $p2 = $arr["vars"]["two"];
    redirect('welcome/'.$p1/$p2);
    */
    }

    public function hello(){
    echo 'connected';
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

When i run `get.php`,i get a blank screen. Why is this the case?.I have error reporting on.Could the reason be the hexadecimal that i am passing as a parameter?.

Comment: Do you see anything if open `http://localhost/app/welcome/entry/` in browser?

Comment: Nope.Also when i open `http://localhost/app/welcome/entry/613A313A7B733A343A2276617273223B613A323A7B733A333A226F6E65223B733A353A2268656C6C6F223B733A333A2274776F223B733A353A22776F726C64223B7D7D` i see nothing

Comment: so if there is nothing - there is nothing. And why do you use another link? where your CI instance installed? `app` or `Qplatform`? just get it ready for browser first.

Comment: Sure, you are so smart and complicated. It is out of my mind to get your ideas :-) I just try to help you. If your CI application doesn't generate expected response for browser, how can you go forward? it is like if you want to drive even if your engine is not working. You have to start your engine first.

Comment: I am not doubting your skill.I am just saying.Sorry if you got it wrong.I've deleted the comment to avoid any confusion.My apologies and thanks for your help.

Comment: You did nothing to sorry about, just fix your CI application first

Comment: Just try to replace function to :  `public function entry(){
    echo 'entry function in welcome controller called';
    }` for example

Comment: Entry is being called i have checked.The problem lies in the hex to string conversion.

Comment: no, the problem is not working as expected CI controller

Comment: I used hex2bin function and now everything works well.You try it.

Answer (score 0):

I used `hex2bin` function and now my code works as expected

```
public function entry($in){
    $in = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $arr = hex2bin($in);
    $array = unserialize($arr);
    $p1 = $arr["vars"]["one"];
    //print_r($array);
    $p1 = $array["vars"]["one"];
    echo $p1;
    /**
    $p1 = $arr["vars"]["one"];
    $p2 = $arr["vars"]["two"];
    redirect('welcome/'.$p1/$p2);
    */
    }
```